# Concatenate string to get a variable name Python

Tags: python, variables, concatenation

I have a function in python with 3 arguments:

`def checkmsg(text, type, mac):`

and the **type** and **mac** are 2 variables that i pass, **type** can be *Alarms* or *Warnings*, and **mac**: *1* or *2*
so i need to store the **text** element (it can be a single element or an array) in a **status** variable (i have 4 variables in a class)

`status.Alarms1, status.Alarms2, status.Warnings1, status.Warnings2`

so i need first to check if the **text** element is the same as the one in the **status**, if different do something and then store it,
so my questions are how can i access to the content and than update the content of the **status** variable having to choose it from the 2 variable passed to the function ?

P.S. (I can change the structure of the **status** 4 variable if it helps)

Comment: Where is your code and what problems do you have with it?

Comment: Use a dictionary and store your stuff under a cool name:   `mydict[(type,mac)]=text`

Comment: please add your code before asking your question, we can't help you writing code

Comment: If you really want to do it, `getattr(status, type + mac)`

Answer (score 1):

Answering your question directly:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Status:
    Alarms1: str
    Alarms2: str
    Warnings1: str
    Warnings2: str


status = Status(Alarms1="", Alarms2="", Warnings1="", Warnings2="")

def checkmsg(text, type_, mac):
    var = f"{type_}{mac}"
    old_text = getattr(status, var)
    if text != old_text:
        print(f"Setting {text} as new value of {var}")
        setattr(status, var, text)
    else:
        print(f"{var} is already set to {text}")

checkmsg("whatever", "Warnings", 1)
checkmsg("whatever more", "Alarms", 2)
checkmsg("whatever again", "Warnings", 1)
checkmsg("whatever more", "Alarms", 2)
```

And when run, it'll print

```
Setting whatever as new value of Warnings1
Setting whatever more as new value of Alarms2
Setting whatever again as new value of Warnings1
Alarms2 is already set to whatever more
```

However, DO NOT DO THIS. This is black magic you don't need. Use dictionary to store your status.